# Database publishing to Word 2003 document / template

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-word, reporting

I have a webapp in wich data is collected, also pictures can be uploaded.
At the moment SSRS 2005 is used to generate reports to present the collected data.
This solution does not give the end users the flexibilty they need.
What they want is a word document prefilled with the data and images from the database, but also the abillity to customize and add content to the report.

I'm trying getting this done using Word 2003 / VBA but this isn't quite easy to get a maintanable template.
The problem is, theres no good support for repeating groups such as tables and lists.

Any suggestions how to solve this usecase, so the document gets generated and the post production can be done in Word?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) to do this before.  Aspose also makes a separate product to do this in Java, but I haven't personally used it.

You would build a template and then you can do a merge with your data into the template to create the document for your users.

Comment: Thanks, ill look in to that, though i'd rather dont wouldn't use a third party solution...

Comment: If you're looking for a free option you could use Word automation, but it wasn't designed to run server-side so there are scalability and stability issues. (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)